# Build failure due to 3rd party JAR dependency using artifactory

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, artifactory

I have imported a 3rd party JAR (not available in Maven repository) into my project, it built fine in the dev environment. However in the CI environment where we have a central artifactory (http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory+User+Guide). While building, I am getting the error

```
Failed to read artifact descriptor for: com.abc.client:client-parent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
......
......
Caused by: org.apache.maven.model.resolution.UnresolvableModelException: Could not find artifact com.abc.client:client-parent:pom:1.0-SNAPSHOT
```

I opened the 3rd party JAR and checked the POM. It does have that parent in it.

```
<groupId>com.abc.client</groupId>
<artifactId>client-java</artifactId>
.....
.....
<parent>
    <groupId>com.abc.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>client-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
</parent>
```

Not sure, if the build happens fine in one env why it fails in CI.
Does the artifactory handle the artifacts differently?

Comment: Do you have that 3rd party artifact on your artifactory? Do you have in your `<repositories>` declared your local artifactory? and url path to the snapshot repository? checkout the http://jlorenzen.blogspot.com/2007/09/how-to-effectively-use-snapshot.html

Comment: @ant Yes. I have got the 3rd party JAR imported in the artifactory as I did in my dev env. However, it only fails in CI. Note: I havent imported parent in dev or CI environment as I do not have that.

Comment: I think it needs parent. Are you sure in your dev env there is no trace of parent artifact? Check ~/.m2/repository folder

Comment: @Alf : No there is no trace I checked the directory

Comment: did you try upload parent pom.xml to repo manager?